# Javascript onscroll event not being called

Tags: javascript, ajax, events

I have an instant chat program I've created with HTML5/CSS, Asynch. Javascript and PHP. I have an interval that is constantly checking the user's chat box `div` is scrolled to the bottom for user convenience. This became a problem when a user wished to scroll up to view previous messages so I tried the `onscroll` event to stop the interval. I couldn't get this to work and so have gone the longer way around by using the `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events to start and stop the interval.

This works perfectly fine for desktop computers as they have a visible mouse. For mobile devices however, such as my Windows phone - which the program is primarily designed for, there is an issue as you first have to tap the message box (presumably to first move the invisible mobile mouse over the chat box) and then scroll with the finger movement to scroll unaffected.

This isn't a major problem as I could inform mobile users to first tap then scroll, but I feel that successfully using the `onscroll` event would match the usability with desktop users.

Are there known issues with the `onscroll` event? I dare say I'm familiar with JS events and can use them appropriately, but this is the only event I haven't managed to get to work, in FF or IE.

Any thoughts or help would be appreciated,
Lee.

Here are the current events that manage the scrollcheck on/off, where ScrollCheck() is the function that checks the scroll position and moves it if not at the bottom and scrollInterval is the global var that holds the id of the interval.

```
document.getElementById('messages').onmouseover = function()
{
    clearInterval(scrollInterval);
}

document.getElementById('messages').onmouseout = function()
{
    scrollInterval = setInterval(ScrollCheck, 300);
}
```

I simply replaced the `onmouseover` event to `onscroll` without any luck.

Comment: Question needs code? What have you done?

Comment: What happens if your onscroll event handler does nothing more than log "Got here!" to the console? Does that work?

Comment: @dgvid the event is being fired, I tested with an alert. Although I realised that the scroll of the ScrollCheck interval is actually firing this too. I need to redesign part of this, probably by adding Kolink's addition below.

Comment: @Lee, this is not enough code, we don't know your HTML, your `ScrollCheck` function, you should create a reduction in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: It turns out the event is firing, there's a conflict with it between another function too. I'm just about the fix the conflict.

Comment: @Lee this is why you should create reductions outside of your environment, you often find the problem when you do that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I make a chat page, I only check the scroll when new messages are added:

```
var currentScroll = elem.scrollTop, oldmaxScroll = elem.scrollHeight-elem.clientHeight;
// add new message(s) here
var newmaxScroll = elem.scrollHeight-elem.clientHeight;
if( currentScroll == oldmaxScroll) elem.scrollTop = newmaxScroll;
```

Comment: If I had a dollar for every time I asked myself that question after hours of work, I wouldn't need to work XD

Comment: Hah, well thank you for that. It's a nifty little addition. I'm going to implement it now.